# How to display the total transfer speed in FileZilla?

Tags: filezilla

Is there any way to display the total transfer speed in FileZilla? I can see the transfer speed for each individual file, but not the total.

Comment: You mean for the session and/or the current connection/site?

Comment: @random current connection/site